# Is opening a thread in C# related to a CPU thread?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, cpu-usage

I am recording multiple usb cameras using a 3rd party library. For that I record each camera’s data on a separate thread in C#. The problem is that application sometimes fails to fetch all the data. 
Therefore I wonder if opening the C# threads might block my CPU threads as my CPU is 4 core / 4 threads. Are CPU cores/threads related to threads we initialize in C#?

Comment: Please define "block a thread" and "intensive". Also, explain why you think this will be a problem.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed explanation what you are doing with the camera, and how you are running in terms of architecture? Are you using your camera to sample a picture every other minute or continuously dumping what the camera exposes to HDD?

Comment: Don't mix up .NET Threads with OS Threads. They are an abstraction and do not map necessarily 1:1.

Comment: I am recording videos of multiple cameras ... while having many transactions going so i want to know if i am opening 4 threads and my cpu is 4 cores 4 thread ... Will my 4 threads block the cpu while recording video ??

Comment: I suppose recording videos is a cpu intensive task or in other terms something that will last for a long time blocking a cpu core from handling any other transactions .. that is my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends on how you're going to accomplish this task. Recording camera video probably comes as a functionality of some 3rd party library, and that lib's API may already need your UI (main) thread in order to do do a task. If you're implementing your own low-level recording API and wish to receive data from that API then you may want to run data fetching in a separate thread simply using:

```
Task.Run(()=> {
  // new thread running - your data fetching code here
});
```

This way, your main thread won't be blocked and awaiting on the new thread will yield the results from your camera API.

Comment: I am recording a video with a 3rd party camera .dll library

Comment: Starting each recording camera in a separate thread

Comment: Some times it doesnt record correctly so im thinking its a cpu threads problem ??

Comment: If it doesn't record correctly, can you check in the task manager if your CPU is close to 100%? - that might cause some issues.

Comment: I want to generally understand the relation between threads in c# and cpu cores howerver  not always ... it might get high but not 100%

Comment: But I am assuming that a task that runs for 5 mins will block any other tasks from running

Comment: C# Thread is not directly related to a CPU thread. Each CPU core can run hundreds of thousands of threads, performing context switching between them so that they seem to work simultaneously. What you should do is to allow TPL to do the heavy work of assigning Threads to CPU cores using aforementioned Task.Run() (link to doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming).

Comment: Other than mentioned, your C# application may fail to record the cameras due to .dll library limitations, high set FPS or simply slow PC for the task you have.

Comment: Maybe limitations ... as I test it on my laptop runs smoothly while on the pc that I am willing to run it on crashes on the 5th or 6th try of recording but im not sure of it is a camera related issue of cpu related issue .. noting that in the event viewer of the windows it shows hardware issue related error

Comment: You probably won’t see any error messages because the problem probably arises from within the library itself where you might be loosing some buffer data.

Comment: Maybe you can change some of the lib’s params, like FPS or set smaller resolution. Which library do you use, by the way?

Comment: I use ozeki camera sdk ... with low resolution maybe like 300×300 or something like this i dont remember and 30Fps maybe sometimes try like 1 fps

Comment: Sure, you can try smaller FPS but that depends on your requirements. I don’t remember another libraries unfortunately. I recommend you to open a new thread because this thread is heavily out of its main content.

Answer (score 0):

That totally depends on the way you are using the thread. I can think of at least 3 different scenarios - 1. Your cameraThread is defined as a high priority, and as such (even with the time slicing) takes 99% of the time. 2. Your cameraThread is run with the tasks thread pool, and as such it is being blocked and is blocking at random with other threads (resource contention). and 3. your camera recorder is happening in a low priority in the background.

Comment: Well i run a normal thread to start recording a video... maybe multiple cameras opening a thread for each camera ... however sometimes while having many transactions a camera does not record correctly ... so thats why i am asking if i am running 4 cameras with 4 threads and my cpu is a 4 core 4 threads will that reserve a cpu thread per task ?

Comment: No, of course not. You have no control over which thread goes to which core processor, and furthermore, there are other things running in the background, like your operating system, your background services and other programs.